# int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'generator'

Tags: python, class

I am stuck with two errors, and I assume it comes from my misuse of the classes, but I can't figure out how to fix that...

I get :

*AttributeError: Organism instance has no attribute 'remove'*

or

*int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'generator'*

```
def filtre_vecteurs(organisms):
  nb_organisms = len(organisms)
  vector_size = len(organisms[0].vector)
  for i in range(vector_size):
    tmp = 0
    for j in range(nb_organisms):
        organisms[j].vector[i] = int(organisms[j].vector[i])
        tmp += organisms[j].vector[i]
    if tmp == nb_organisms :
       for j in range(0, nb_organisms):
           organisms[j].remove(organisms[j].vector[i])
return organisms
```

"organisms" is a list of objets

"organisms[0].vector" :vector of the first object of the list

a vector looks like this [1,0,1,1...]

thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: Could you give a [mcve] and the full traceback(s)?

Answer (score 0):

Your errors are:

1. AttributeError: Organism instance has no attribute 'remove'

This is in line `organisms[j].remove(organisms[j].vector[i])`
Here, it seems `organisms[j]` which is an `organism` has no `remove()` method. You ***probably*** want to remove the element `organisms[j].vector[i]` from `organisms[j].vector`:

`organisms[j].vector.remove(organisms[j].vector[i])`

2. int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'generator'

This is due to line:

`organisms[j].vector[i] = int(organisms[j].vector[i])`

Are you sure that `organisms[j].vector[i]` is a number/string?. Can you try printing it and see if it is indeed a number/string?

Answer (score -1):

Here are things to look at:

Error 1:

What is the type of organisms[j].vector[i]? From the error message, it appears as though it is a generator, so has no conversion to int.

Error 2:

What does your organism class look like?

From the line:

```
 organisms[j].remove(organisms[j].vector[i])
```

which I presume causes your second error. Your Organism class has no method called 'remove'.